# Laravel Regex Validation for Uploaded File Names

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm trying to use the Validator class to check that the filename of an uploaded file matches a regular expression however it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm not sure what it's trying to match against but it doesn't seem to be the file name.

What I'm describing as the filename is:

```
Request::all()['file']->getClientOriginalName()
```

Where `file` is the name of the uploaded file variable.

Here's the code I'm testing:

```
$input = Request::all();
$rules = array(
    'file' => array('required', 'max:3000', 'regex:/^[\w\-\. ]+\.(zip|rar|gz|tar|tgz|tar\.Z|tbz2|tar\.lzma|bz2|tlz|7z)$/'),
);

$validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

dump($input['file']);

if ($validation->fails())
{
    return new Response($validation->errors()->first(), 400);
}

return new Response('success', 200);
```

Here's the value dump of `$input['file']`:

```
UploadedFile {#27
  -test: false
  -originalName: "test.zip"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -size: 1376044
  -error: 0
}
```

The validation always fails with the error `'The file format is invalid.'`.

The regex only seems to succeed when I use `/^.*$/`.  I've also tried `/^test.zip$/` and `.*test.zip.*` and they both fail for this file too.